# List of Rails Model Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does someone have a complete list of model types that be specified when generating a model scaffolding

e.g.

```
foo:string 
bar:text 
baz:boolean
```

etc...

And what do these types map to in terms of default UI elements? Text field, Text area, radio button, checkbox, etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails generate model field:type -what are the options for field:type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384284/rails-generate-model-fieldtype-what-are-the-options-for-fieldtype)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

The attributes are SQL types, hence the following are supported:

- `:binary`
- `:boolean`
- `:date`
- `:datetime`
- `:decimal`
- `:float`
- `:integer`
- `:primary_key`
- `:string`
- `:text`
- `:time`
- `:timestamp`

These are documented under **column** in the [Active Record API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column).

Comment: Your link went tweets up (I think that's the phrase).  If you can link to some authentic documentation, that'd be tweet i mean sweet.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be a more accurate link, now http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Comment: Where does :references fit into this?  Is it database specific?

Comment: i wish to add for those reading in future that when creating a migration etc car:references comes in very handy for creating a car_id foreign key.

Comment: and now it's here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column - i updated the answer

Comment: where is type `:digest` in the documentation? it is seen at the schema.rb level `password_digest`. dont you need it for devise or running `rails g scaffold User name:string password:digest`?

Answer (score 49):

You can use the following *basic* field types in model scaffolding, all are supported in ActiveRecord supported databases without any extra gem (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite):

- `:binary`
- `:boolean`
- `:date`
- `:datetime`
- `:decimal`
- `:float`
- `:integer`
- `:primary_key`
- `:string`
- `:text`
- `:time`
- `:timestamp`

In the scaffold generator you can also declare the foreign references using `:references` field type, which additionaly adds a `belongs_to` reference in the new model.

If you use Rails 4 and PostgreSQL, you can take advantage of these:

- `:hstore`
- `:array`
- `:cidr_address`
- `:ip_address`
- `:mac_address`

For UI mapping (Model scaffold data type -> HTML), the next image has all the *basic* field types:

[image: Rails data types, scaffolding HTML mapping]

Comment: Rails 5 on PostgreSQL: you can use `add_column :table_name, :field_name, :inet` create a column to store IP addresses. See eg. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-data-types/