# Ruby on Rails generates model field:type - what are the options for field:type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to generate a new model and forget the syntax for referencing another model's ID. I'd look it up myself, but I haven't figured out, among all my Ruby on Rails documentation links, how to find the definitive source.

`$ rails g model Item name:string description:text` (and here either `reference:product` or `references:product`). But the better question is *where* or *how* can I look for this kind of silliness easily in the future?

Note: I've learned the hard way that if I mistype one of these options and *run my migration* then Ruby on Rails will totally screw up my database... and `rake db:rollback` is powerless against such screwups. I'm sure I'm just not understanding something, but until I do... the "detailed" information returned by `rails g model` still leaves me scratching...

Comment: What about :uniq and :index field options? Like in "rails g model title body:text tracking_id:integer:uniq". I couldn't find documentation for those. Are there any more?

Comment: `rails generate model --help`

Comment: Using a version control would provide you with an easy way to rollback any generated files. And if the problem is in the database... well, you can always do db:schema:load

Answer (score 506, accepted):

```
:primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp,
:time, :date, :binary, :boolean, :references
```

See the [table definitions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) section.

Comment: hmm...no mention of `:reference` or `:references` in your answer *or* an explanation of how to pass it to generators in the link you provided?!?

Comment: Example: `rails generate model Song name:string mp3url:string description:text` --will make a model Song with properties name with type string, etc..

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Selected this as the answer but know that **:references** is also an option.

Comment: useful link related to this answer:  http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/

Comment: Is there some documentation that actually *defines* these column types?  For instance, how does `string` differ from `text`?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-table

The mappings to native database types aren't explicitly defined as that would have to be done for every database supported. However, a sensible mapping will occur. In the case of string and text, I believe it's varchar(255) and text respectively.

The short answer is suck and see. Either look through the open source code or create a database with your chosen adaptor and examine the result using the command line or a visual tool.

Comment: What about :uniq and :index field options? Like in "rails g model title body:text tracking_id:integer:uniq". I couldn't find documentation for those. Are there any more?

Comment: @Kangur the `uniq` and `index` suffixes (and all the types) are documented in the usage of `rails generate model`. Run `rails g model` to see the usage docs.

Comment: Another (not well documented) option is `belongs_to` as can be seen [here](https://coderwall.com/p/f5mdoq/using-belongs_to-with-scaffold-generator-to-quickly-create-associations). But I think it does the exact same as `references`.

Comment: Unfortunate that @Meltemi's subject line and body of his question didn't match. Nevertheless, there are some helpful comments on this page, thanks.

Comment: Your link is unhelpful.

Comment: answered my question!

Comment: Just to mention that the list of available column types is now expanded to:
:primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :bigint, :float, :decimal, :numeric, :datetime, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean.
(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column)

Comment: :token is also now an option.

Answer (score 192):

To create a model that references another, use the Ruby on Rails model generator:

```
$ rails g model wheel car:references
```

That produces **app/models/wheel.rb**:

```
class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

And adds the following migration:

```
class CreateWheels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :wheels do |t|
      t.references :car

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :wheels
  end
end
```

When you run the migration, the following will end up in your **db/schema.rb**:

```
$ rake db:migrate

create_table "wheels", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "car_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

As for documentation, a starting point for rails generators is [Ruby on Rails: A Guide to The Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) which points you to [API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) for more about available field types.

Comment: slightly out of date with the comment, but this is _the_ answer for this question. +1

Answer (score 8):

`$ rails g model Item name:string description:text product:references`

I too found the guides difficult to use. Easy to understand, but hard to find what I am looking for.

Also, I have temp projects that I run the `rails generate` commands on. Then once I get them working I run it on my real project.

Reference for the above code:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#associating-models

Answer (score 3):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org should be a good site if you're trying to get through the basic stuff in Ruby on Rails.

Here is a link to associate models while you generate them:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#associating-models

Answer (score 3):

Remember to not capitalize your text when writing this command.
For example:

Do write:

```
rails g model product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

**Do not write:**

```
rails g Model product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

At least it was a problem to me.

Comment: Wait?!? What? I capitalize my model names all the time!  What "problems" are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not talking about the name of your model, but the name 'Model'.
I tried to create a model like this:
rails g Model product title:string
and got: Could not find generator Model.
so i tried it like this:
rails g model product title:string
and it worked.

Comment: Ah. Hadn't encountered that b4. Good tip!

Comment: (It's not the model name that's the issue, it's the word `model` as referring to the generator. `rails g model Product …` is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my code was a little bit different.

```
def new
 @project = Project.new
end
```

And my form looked like this:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
     and so on....
<% end %>
```

That was totally correct, so I didn't know how to figure it out.

Finally, just adding

```
url: { projects: :create }
```

after

```
<%= form-for @project ...%>
```

worked for me.

Comment: This may be a good answer but I'm not sure how it relates to the OP which is about field types (`:integer`, `:string`, etc…).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple in ROR to create a model that references other.

rails g model Item name:string description:text product:references

This code will add 'product_id' column in the Item table

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of data types you can mention while creating model, some examples are:

```
:primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean, :references
```

syntax:

```
field_type:data_type
```