# Rails Scaffolding Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Rails Model Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260345/list-of-rails-model-types)

I am working on my own to learn RoR. I came across this:

```
rails g scaffold blog title:string body:text –skip-stylesheets
```

now this creates a kind of blog. I want to find out what more arguments u can pass to
the scaffold method.

```
rails g scaffold <argument> title:string body:text –skip-stylesheets
```

are those listed anywhere? I had a look on rails api but did not find anything. maybe I was looking at the wrong place. any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually just the name of the model that will be created - so it can be anything (that is a valid class name when the first letter is uppercased).

Answer (score 7):

`bundle exec rails g scaffold --help`