# How Should I use percent values in my database for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am very new to Ruby on Rails, and I was looking for a way to include decimals in my database. For example, if I wanted to take a total score and and multiply it by a certain rate  to get a new score. Would I use rails g model student name:string,score:integer,rate:decimal ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260345/list-of-rails-model-types

Comment: When using `rails g model`, attributes should be space separated, not comma separated, so `rails g model student name:string score:integer rate:decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use that to generate your model. But, could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? The first statement "was looking for a way to include decimals in my database." - seems orthogonal to the "would i use..." question.

Comment: oh sorry. I was working on a mini shop project as a project to help me learn. With this app, I am displaying a list of a items and randomly assign a user a discount price. How would I Incorporate the rate of the discount in the database?

Comment: The rate can be stored in the db as a base of 1 or a base of 100. Whichever way you choose to store, your calculations should reflect it so that the end result is achieved. Also, such conversions, if any, should [preferably] be at the model level.